# Why when I deserialize with JSON.NET ignores my default value?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, deserialization, default-value

I'm using JSON.NET as my main serializer.

This is my model, look that I've setted some `JSONProperties` and a `DefaultValue`.

```
public class AssignmentContentItem
{
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Qty")]
    [DefaultValue(1)]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

When I serialize a `List<AssignmentContentItem>`, it doing a good work:

```
private static JsonSerializerSettings s = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
};
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{"Id":"Q0"},{"Id":"Q4"},{"Id":"Q7"}]
```

But when I'd like to deserialize this jsonContent, the property Qty is always 0 and is not set to the default value. I mean, when I deserialize that jsonContent, as DefaultValue for Quantity should be one instead of 0.

```
public static List<AssignmentContentItem> DeserializeAssignmentContent(string jsonContent)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AssignmentContentItem>>(jsonContent, s);
}
```

What should I do

Comment: Did you try the DefaultValueHandling.Populate setting?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `DefaultValue` attribute does not set the value of the property. See this question: [.NET DefaultValue attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329868/net-defaultvalue-attribute)

What you might be better off doing is setting the value in the constructor:

```
public class AssignmentContentItem
{
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Qty")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public AssignmentContentItem()
    {
        this.Quantity = 1;
    }
}
```

Where this line:

```
AssignmentContentItem item =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AssignmentContentItem>("{\"Id\":\"Q0\"}");
```

Results in an `AssignmentContentItem` with its `Quantity` set to `1`.

Comment: You can add `[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]` if the json does not have the property and it's nullable so it will take the value set in the constructor otherwise it will set to null

Answer (score 13):

You can use the the DefaultValueHandling.Populate setting so that Json.Net will populate the created object with the default value.

```
public static List<AssignmentContentItem> DeserializeAssignmentContent(string jsonContent)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AssignmentContentItem>>(jsonContent, new JsonSerializerSettings
    { 
            DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate, 
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore 
    });
}
```

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm