# Best way to only allow the setting of a property while deserializing a JsonProperty?

Tags: c#, json, properties

I want to read in the id but I don't want it to be set once it's read in. The _processing variable is set while reading in the file and deserializing so it can be set. Is there a built-in more elegant way of handling this?

```
    private string _id;
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (_processing) // Only allow when reading the file
            {
                _id = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `private set` ?

Comment: Just use a private setter along with [JsonProperty]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066947/private-setters-in-json-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use init only properties (since C#9.0) (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init):

```cs
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
public string Id { get; init; }
```

If not...

```cs
private string _id;
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
public string Id
{
    get { return _id; }
    set { _id ??= value; } // could also throw if _id is not null
}
```

Unrelated but helpful link on setting default property values if they are not found in the json: [Default value for missing properties with JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29611445/default-value-for-missing-properties-with-json-net)

Comment: The non-init setter solution does however give the illusion to the caller that the ID can be set to another value. You can set it a second time, but nothing will happen. To prevent this you can also throw an InvalidOperationException.

Comment: Sure. It’s up to the implementor to decide

Answer (score 1):

In C# 7.3 and earlier you can use the null-coalescing operator like so:

```
    set
    {
        _id = _id ?? value;
    }
```

In C# 8.0 and later you can do:

```
    set
    {
        _id ??= value;
    }
```

**??=** operator doesn't evaluate its right-hand operand if the left-hand operand evaluates to non-null.

Comment: This does however give the illusion to the caller that the ID can be set to another value. You can set it a second time, but nothing will happen. To prevent this you can also throw an InvalidOperationException.

Answer (score 1):

I think just using a private setter would work. Just don't call it again.
You can also leave out the property name if these are the same.

```
    private string _id;
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        private set
        {
            _id = value;
        }
    }
```

or

```
    [JsonProperty]
    public string id { get; private set; }
```