# Wpf Toolkit PropertyGrid DefaultValue Attribute Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit, propertygrid

I use PropertyGrid from WPF Toolkit and using default Editor.
I want to set the default value using DefaultValue Attribute, but it doesn't work.

This is my model:

```
    public class PropertyDummyViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        [DisplayName(@"Double Value Default Editor")]
        [DefaultValue(70)]
        public double DoubleValueDefaultEditor { get; set; }
    }
```

The XAML of PropertyDummyView:

```
<Grid ...
    x:Name="PropertyGrid">
    <xctk:PropertyGrid SelectedObject="{Binding Path=DataContext, ElementName=PropertyGrid}" />
</Grid>
```

And the PropertyGrid is:

```
    public void ShowDialog()
    {
        var model = new PropertyDummyViewModel();
        var view = new PropertyDummyView() { DataContext = model };
        var window = new Window() { Content = view };
        window.ShowDialog();
    }
```

When I run it, the value of the property is 0, instead of 70. How to set default value on Wpf Toolkit PropertyGrid control?

Comment: Could it be because the `double` gets initialized automatically with `0.0d` as it is a value type? I don't know anything about the property grid so this is just a guess. Maybe the default value attribute only works with `Nullable` and / or reference types. I that should be the case then you will have to set the default values in the constructor of your model instead.

Comment: Yes it works, but I want cleaner code, without constructor that set the default values and not scroll up down to see the default values. The DefaultValueAttribute as far as I know is used by Winform PropertyGrid.
But I think the other clean solution is using C# 6 feature:


        public double DoubleValueDefaultEditor { get; set; } = 70;


I am creating some default property editors as well. So I am wondering how to set default value using DefaultValueAttribute on my own editor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329868/net-defaultvalue-attribute

Comment: @jstreet, yes, that is very clear for my goal, "Cannot be used to auto property and just a decorator", so I must just forget about it and just use Frank J suggestion, just using default value.