# C# - Setting default int value in BinaryFormatter deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter

I had the following class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Message
{  public string messageSummary;
   public DateTime messageDate;
}
```

Later, i decided to add to the class another int field - messageNumber

```
[Serializable]
public class Message
{  
    public string messageSummary;
    public DateTime messageDate;
    public int messageNumber;
}
```

In deserialization, when deserializing an old serialized `Message` class(without `messageNumber` field) - how can I set the default value of messageNumber to -1 instead of 0?

I tried to define a method with  `[OnDeserialized()]` attribute, but `messageNumber` is already set there to 0. 0 can also the value of `messageNumber`, so I can't override it in that method.
Is it possible to set the default value to -1?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you used DefaultValueAttribute https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329868/net-defaultvalue-attribute ? In your case is it posiible to use properties instead of fields?

Answer (score 2):

`[OnDeserialized]` happens after deseralization. If you want to set default value you can define `[OnDeserializing]` [serialization callback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/version-tolerant-serialization#serialization-callbacks)

```
[OnDeserializing]
private void SetMessageNumberDefault(StreamingContext sc)
{
    messageNumber = -1;     // add default value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try DefaultValueAttribute as describe in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8).
Than you can try solution as follow:

```
[Serializable]
public class Message
{
    public const int Int_Default = -1;
    public string messageSummary;
    public DateTime messageDate;
    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(Int_Default)]
    public int messageNumber { get; set; } = Int_Default;
}
```